Does a gap in a rafter indicate foundation problems?
So I recently had my foundation inspected and the foundation repair company noted some settlement in some areas. I don't notice any underlying issues with the house other then one door frame is not square. No cracked bricks along the exterior, in the foundation, etc. Guy climbed into my attic and found one rafter that's slightly separated.
I painted about 11 years ago and no new cracks have formed in the paint or anything above the windows or doors and windows open and close just fine. He proposed installing 7 steel piers. Could this just be old settlement that I should keep an eye on or should I address this ASAP?  I am also in Texas where foundation issues are quite common and have a double poured foundation.
I have attached pictures of the elevation map, rafter, and corner with the -2.4 inch settlement. I will be adding downspout extenders and splash blocks ASAP.



My neighbor had foundation work recently so it piqued my attention. Here is also a picture of the crooked door jam. It's been that way for as long as I can remember. It sticks when it rains.



Why did you find a need for a foundation inspection?   The pics don't show anything that indicates a definite foundation issue.

The pic of the rafters, just look like poor carpentry work. The pic at the outside corner looks like the soil got washed away and is lower. Nothing that shows a foundation issue.

Yes, it could be old. The only way to know is to watch for signs that it is continuing to settle. Or you could put in the additional support now and not have to worry about it.

I am considering doing just that, however I am concerned if I mess with the already settled foundation in this corner that it will cause issues as is very common in other parts of the house.

Or get other inspections.

Second opinion is always wise. Often third opinion, and take the one that sounds most reasonable (usually the one on the middle).

I would think about slapping something rigid in that gap (maybe hot mud?) to fill it.  With a filler it will be easier to see if it continues to move.
